# What is type of design (Youtube music background and thumbnail) called?

Tags: layers, images, terminology

I have found some examples where the thumbnails and the background of the following YouTube videos has these characteristics:

- Cover album at the background of the video.
- The cover is also in higher size behing the "smaller" cover album.

These are some examples I found:

[Phenomenon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4EpbuqJcRw)

[image: sample #1]

[Rockefeller Street](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Me6YNe9tg)

[image: sample #2]

[In the Shadows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfcD2fDM0ME)

[image: sample #3]

[The Cage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk3XJ4ztzFo)

[image: sample #4]

I'm not a web/graphic designer, but I found this design interesting. Did this kind of design has a name?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm interesting in **get any official documentation *(if exists)* about the name of this kind of design**, because, looking in Stack Oveflow *([about the grey boxes in YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49962206/4092887))*, the only answer shows a name, but I don't know if this is a real-official name.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I'm a graphic designer and when I see something I like, I just copy it. It seems to be just what you describe: A cover image, some text and a blurred, scaled up version of the cover in the background. What sort of  additional information are you hoping to find?

Comment: Videos use this same technique (either a static frame [like this](https://codepen.io/ig_design/details/xmZpbo) or one that updates as the video changes). Not sure what the name of the technique is, if it has a name

Comment: All of your examples in the question are by YouTube's [auto-generated topic channels](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2579942?hl=en)

Comment: ZachSaucier you are correct, previous examples came from auto-generated YouTube channels. @Wolff I was wondering if such technique has a name *(but it seems it doesn't)*.